# CALayer removeAnimationForKey: throws CABasicAnimation length: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, ios7, core-animation, cabasicanimation, caanimation

I have a category on `CALayer` that adds and removes animations. I have a rotation animation that works perfectly and I have an `-endRotating` method. Here is how I've implemented it:

```
CAAnimation *anim = [self animationForKey:ROTATION_KEY];
if(anim){
    [self removeAnimationForKey:anim];
}
```

`anim` is an instance of `CABasicAnimation` in the method, which is correct. However, `[self removeAnimationForKey:anim];` causes an unrecognized selector to be sent to my animation instance:

```
-[CABasicAnimation length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xba2bf40
```

Is this a bug in UIKit, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my animation for reference:

```
-(void)beginRotatingWithAngularVelocity:(float)velocity{
    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 999999;
    rotationAnimation.duration = velocity;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI * 2];
    [self addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:ROTATION_KEY];
}
```

Why is remove method trying to access `length` of my animation?

Comment: This is just a typo. You are passing the actual animation object instead of the key sat eh argument.

Comment: Opps, how couldn't I see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the signature of `removeAnimationForKey:`

```
- (void)removeAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key
```

As you can see it expects an `NSString` object (in your case probably `ROTATION_KEY`), not a `CAAnimation`.

Comment: I have no idea why I was passing the animation instead of the key. Thanks :)